# Gunicorn only giving 400 through socket

Tags: django, http, nginx, gunicorn

Hi I am using gunicorn to host a django app. The command I am using to run gunicorn is

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind unix:/home/myuser/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application
```

When I try to ping it with command

```
curl --unix-socket /home/myuser/myapp/myapp.sock http:localhost/api
```

I get 400 errors. But if I run the same gunicorn command with a bind address of

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 5 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 myapp.wsgi:application
```

And then curl the same address I get a 200 and the response I am looking for.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with the gunicorn socket implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, then I checked `DEBUG = True` in settings.py. It is false by default and if you don't set it, you will get 400 answer. Hope this helps.